# Multiple canonical or alternate URLs for the page with same content

Tags: domains, canonical-url

I am creating a russian website that will use IDN domain ".рф".

But it will be also accessible with normal domain. So every page will have 2 urls, 1 in russian and 1 in english, but content will be the same (just logo will be changed) example:

```
www.example.com/example
пример.рф/пример
```

How should I manage that? Can I use 2 canonical urls? Should I set the second one as alternate?

Comment: Search engines won't index both.   Choosing one as canonical allows you to tell them which one you want indexed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, I know. I can index russian domain in yandex.ru and in google I prefer english version. So I just set english domain as canonical and russian url as alternate. Should I set any attribute?

Comment: That is an interesting twist.   I'm not sure how you set canonical tags so that different search engines have different canonical URLs.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yandex doesn't read meta tags, you just set that in webmaster panel. So I have to set canonical just for google. But I don't know if it is a right way to set alternate without any attribute

Comment: "yandex doesn't read meta tags" - The [Yandex webmaster docs](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml) appear to suggest otherwise and include reference to the `rel="canonical"` link element. Just to clarify... the content of these two sites are the same, including the same language? Which language?

Comment: @w3dk I've read that settings in webmaster ovverides meta info. Website will be in russian, same content (logo changes) but website will be available using .рф domain and .com domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple to do it for Google, in the Russian version, just add `<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/example" />` in the head section of the page

I hope you're managing for Yandex!

Comment: The `rel="canonical"` applies to the `link` element, not the `meta` element and the `href` should reference an absolute URL. However, [Yandex does appear to support `rel="canonical"`](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml#canonical) so this would not seem to do what the OP requires.